# Lost all connection via Putty and RDP after upgrading to ubuntu 18

Tags: upgrade, ssh, remote-desktop

I'm a beginner in Ubuntu. I had a RDP connection to connect from my Windows10 to a VM with Ubutnu server v. 16.04.5

I launched an upgrade to ubuntu 18 using these commands:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade

The system made its upgrade, and then closed automatically my RDP connection.
Since then, I could not re-connect with my IP address.

This is [the error message on RDP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11GbJ.png)

and here [the error message on Puttty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2yeY.png)

I read in some links on askubuntu suggesting some commands related to ssh. The issue is that I currently have no access to the ubuntu server to make any of these commands.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

1. edit sshd_config:

   > sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config

change PasswordAuthentication and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to yes.

2. restart ssh:

   > /etc/init.d/ssh restart